# Use or pass parent click handler to child component in angular

Tags: angular

How can i use or pass parent click handler to child component in angular? I have use @input decorator to bind parent data for my child component but then parent gets failed to listen of own click events. this [stackblitz](https://angular-ivy-59n5ah.stackblitz.io) is the live code i am using please correct it.

Comment: Did you try with Output() decorator?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Output decorator:

child.component.js

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() listenParentHandler : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  childClick(){
   this.listenParentHandler.emit();
  }
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<app-child (listenParentHandler)="buttonClick()"></app-child>
```

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bswpaj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts

Comment: Thanks!! lissettdm its working exactly what i wanted, just one thing want to ask how to define exact click event type in EventEmitter<any> instead of <any>.

and i believe this the right way to pass parent event o child what you have corrected instead the above one suggest by Pankaj please suggest.

Comment: lissettdm can you please suggest me any network where i can directly ask question to you for better & quick response if i am not able to found here in time.

Comment: For example EventEmitter<number>, is related to the data type you will send on event emit, this.listenParentHandler.emit(1000).

Answer (score 0):

If the parent and child component has tight coupling between each other. For example `tab-group` and `tab` component

```
<tab-group>
  <tab title="Tab 1">Tab 1</tab>
  <tab title="Tab 1">Tab 2</tab>
  <tab title="Tab 2">Tab 3</tab>
</tab-group>
```

In such cases you can use [**`@Host`**](https://angular.io/api/core/Host) decorator to get an access of parent component instance inside ChildComponent. But when you use `Host` decorator it says adds tight coupling between two components.

```
constructor(
   @Host() private parent: ParentComponent
) {}
```

Though you can use `@Optional` decorator incase you don't want to use it with `ParentComponent`, but again it's not appropriate way to use `@Optional()` with `Host` decorator.

[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n5h2ni?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for answer but i want to pass data using appropriate Input or Output Decorators & also current one Forked Stackblitz is not working.

Comment: @Roy I'm sorry, update the link. And added link to `Host` decorator documentation. Can you please check update one?